# Knockout - subscribe event on a dynamically added object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create an array of objects in Knockout. Each object consists of an observable array (which contains a list of alphanumeric codes) and a text field for the description relating to the code. On selection of a code from the list, I want the text field to be updated accordingly. What I'm going to do is use the code to then retrieve the corresponding description from a web service but I still can't get the subscribe event to fire from a selection of the code drop-down list. I need to then get the selected text and update the description field. Here's my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/phykell/tuqQp/

I think the problem is how I'm declaring the subscribe method:

```
self.Items.subscribe(function(data) {   
    alert(data);
    data.Description = data.Code;
});
```

In this sample, I'm just trying to copy the code to the description field (note that I haven't managed to get the Code drop-down list to show the actual Code values yet either!

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: you're very eloquent for a feline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I added a bit of HTML to your code to show the Code value and took away the items variable as it was unnecessary.  I am not sure exactly what you are trying to subscribe to (Knockout automatically subscribes to changes in the items properties, if you are just trying to subscribe to the adding or removal of items then you are doing so already with your code)

http://jsfiddle.net/tuqQp/3/

Note : You need an optionsText attribute for Knockout to know what to show in your list.

```
    <select style="width: 200px;" 
        data-bind="options: $root.availableItems, optionsText: 'Description', value: Code, optionsCaption: '-- Select Code --'">
    </select>
```

**Edit**

Ok I have updated the fiddle to do what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/tuqQp/8/

When you are trying to get a value there is no need to subscribe.  Just create a model (function) and use an observable that is based off the value of whatever you want to depend on.  In the fiddle I made the computed (description) based on the value of code.  Whenever the value of code changes description is called because it is subscribed to it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

I probably shouldn't have included the description field in the availableItems array initialiser as it may be misleading. 

I need to display the code in the drop-down list and only get the description data on demand; the reason for this is that the list will contain perhaps 50 entries and while the codes are just a few characters long the description fields may be quite large.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm trying to subscribe to the Codes drop-down list so that when a code is selected, I can then call my web service, passing the code to the specific method, and populate the description field with the selected code's corresponding description.

Comment: OK - I've updated the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/phykell/tuqQp/4/

As you'll see, I've added a subscribe to the availableItems observable array - the idea (if it worked!) is that when the drop-down list is selected, the function is called and will retrieve the description held against the code and update the description field accordingly.

Comment: Hmm you should be able to make your code work based off the recommendations I gave you, I did open your fiddle but subscribe event was not firing an alert.  Is there something else that you had a question on or did I answer it for you?

Comment: Apologies - I hadn't managed to get the subscribe event firing and that's the issue really. Once I've added my object (containing the code drop-down list and the description text field) to the array, I then need an event to fire on the user selecting a code from the drop-down list - the event should take the code value, call the web service and display the result in the corresponding description field.

Comment: Why would you call the web service if you already have the value of description in your observable array?  Wouldn't you just set the new object's description equal to that value?

Comment: The description field may be very large so I don't want to download it along with the list of codes. I only want to go and get the description for the code once the user has selected the code itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with this - you've solved my problem! :)